# Jquery Load current tab on Next Record

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

Here is a cut down version of my views page

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Company Info</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Notes</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Equipment</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <%= render :partial => 'company_info', :locals => {:f => f} %>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
     <%= render :partial => 'company_notes', :locals => {:f => f} %>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
     <%= render :partial => 'company_equipment', :locals => {:f => f} %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Each tab has these links to go to the next or previous record.

```
<h3><%= link_to '<--- Previous', edit_lead_path(@leads[@previous_lead_index]) %></h3>

<h3><%= link_to 'Next --->', edit_lead_path(@leads[@next_lead_index]) %></h3>
```

every time i click on one of those links it always goes back to the first tab. what i am looking to do is be able to click on the Previous / Next link and it opens the next record edit page with the same tab open...

so if i am in #tabs-3 it will open next record with #tabs-3 open...

The only Javascript i have for these tabs is this so far...

```
$(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
    });
```

**This question has probably been answered somewhere but after reading 20 - 30 of the post i cant find an answer that is relevant to what i am looking for... most of them are just for refreshing the current page not for opening the next record in database...**

Using:

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-themes'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

was able to accomplish this by doing this

```
<h3><%= link_to '<--- Previous', edit_lead_path(@leads[@previous_lead_index]) + "#tabs-3" %></h3>

<h3><%= link_to 'Next --->', edit_lead_path(@leads[@next_lead_index]) + "#tabs-3" %></h3>
```

url will be like this:   `site.com/leads/3007/edit#tabs-3`